# have, get, make

Tags: grammar

If I say" My father has mechanic repair his car" is it correct or I shouldn't use has to make someone to do something?  Should it be always with "had" or if I use pronoun like He,she, it and put has to define the situation

Comment: I am not sure what do the `get` and `make` has to do with your question. If I am understanding correctly, you are asking about the difference between has and had?

Comment: This is the wrong site to ask basic questions about learning English. I’m flagging this for closure here and migration to our other site [ell.se], where you will hopefully get more assistance. :-)

Comment: “He, she, it and put ...”? *Put* isn’t a pronoun.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't correct as it stands because you're missing either an article for the mechanic, or an s if there is more than one of them. You could say "My father has a mechanic repair his car" or "My father has the mechanic repair his car" or "My father has mechanics repair his car." I do personally think it sounds a little better to use the past tense ("My father had a mechanic repair his car"), but that's up to you; there's nothing wrong with using the present tense.

Using has as opposed to get or make is absolutely fine grammatically, though it depends exactly what you want to convey. "My father makes the mechanics repair his car" would make it sound as if he is forcing them to do it.

Comment: very helpful! I guess you are the only one understood the question

Comment: For the present tense, even though it's grammatical as it is (with the one correction), it would sound better to say *My father **is having** a mechanic repair his car*.